# Android animation effect

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to make animation in android like an effect in ipad when we turn the page.
Anyone has a clue for this matter?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly how the turn page animation looks in iPad but a good place to start could be to look how animations with Camera class work.

You could find some help for example here:
http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html